# SAXParser: handle only specific parent childs

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I have xml structure

```
<data>
   <id>id</id>
   <title>dataTitle</title>
   <entry>
      <title>title1</title>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <title>title2</title>
   </entry>
</data>
```

And I want to parse it and save in list only title elements under entry. How can I check in endElement that title is under entry? 
Not I have NullPointerExpception because parser tries to save title which is data child.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    elementOn = true;
    if ("entry".equals(localName)) {
        song = new Song();
    }
}


@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    elementOn = false;

    if ("title".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
        song.setTitle(elementValue);
    } else if ("entry".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
        songList.add(song);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the line that causes the `NullPointerException`

Comment: song.setTitle(elementValue); Because song is not created it startElement is there was no entry element

Comment: you need a `boolean` attribute, that keeps track whether you are within an entry or not.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use a stack to *push* and *pop* the cData at startElement and endElement events respectively. Add a check in the endElement event so that only the data you require is stored